# Compare data between multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server with columns `id, name1, desc1, name2, desc2`. I want to compare `name1, name2` values and `desc1, desc2` values and display the result in another column 'Remarks' .

Something like this

```
id | name1 | desc1 | name2 | desc2
```

Output should be like

```
id | name1 | Desc1 | name2 | desc2 | Remarks
---+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------------------------
 1 | abc   | test1 | xyz   | test2 | Desc and name different
 2 | def   | test3 | ghi   | test3 | Name different
```

There are multiple columns like this in the table to compare.

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.

```
SELECT 
    name1
    ,Desc1
    ,name2
    ,Desc2
    ,(CASE WHEN name1<>name2 THEN 'Name different'
          WHEN Desc1<>Desc2 THEN 'Desc different'
          WHEN name1<>name2 AND Desc1<>Desc2 THEN 'Name and Desc different' 
     END)
FROM tbl
```

Comment: every time returns "Name different"

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to create a user defined function which can do the evaluation of the differences between the fields you need to check and can return the proper "remarks" string. I've setup a SQLFiddle as a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa2cc65/2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name1 ,Desc1 ,name2 ,Desc2 ,
(CASE 
WHEN (name1<>name2) and (Desc1<>Desc2) THEN 'Name and Desc different' 
WHEN name1<>name2 THEN 'Name different' 
WHEN Desc1<>Desc2 THEN 'Desc different'
WHEN (name1=name2) and (Desc1=Desc2) THEN 'Name and Desc Same' 
END) as Remarks
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name1, desc1, name2, desc2, 
        (CASE  WHEN (ISNULL(name1, '') <> ISNULL(name2, '')) AND  (ISNULL(desc1, '') <> ISNULL(desc2, '')) THEN 'Desc and name different' 
                  WHEN (ISNULL(name1, '') = ISNULL(name2, '')) AND (ISNULL(desc1, '') <> ISNULL(desc2, '')) THEN 'Desc different' 
                  WHEN (ISNULL(name1, '') <> ISNULL(name2, '')) AND (ISNULL(desc1, '') = ISNULL(desc2, '')) THEN 'Name different' 
                  WHEN (ISNULL(name1, '') = ISNULL(name2, '')) AND (ISNULL(desc1, '') = ISNULL(desc2, '')) THEN 'Not different' 
        END) as Remarks
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name1, Desc1, name2, desc2,   
   CASE WHEN trim(ISNULL(name1, 'NULL')) <> trim(ISNULL(name2, 'NULL')) AND
             trim(ISNULL(desc1, 'NULL')) <> trim(ISNULL(desc2, 'NULL'))
        THEN 'name and desc different'

        WHEN trim(ISNULL(name1, 'NULL')) <> trim(ISNULL(name2, 'NULL'))
        THEN 'name different' 

        WHEN trim(ISNULL(desc1, 'NULL')) <> trim(ISNULL(desc2, 'NULL')) 
        THEN 'desc different' END as Remarks
from yourtable
```

If a value is null it will not compare unless you check specifically.
You might not need to trim spaces.
I did not get a chance to run this through sql server.